# How I can specify a exact view to new List via client dll?

Tags: list, view, backup, restore

I can create different types of lists, but all the time the default view is applied to the created list. Can I assign a custom view for specific list via client `dll` - `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` ?

Some code bellow:

```
[Test]
public void TestCreateListTasks1()
{
    var list = Site.Lists.Add(new ListCreationInformation()
    {
        Title = "TestWithVIEW2",
        Description = "TestWithVIEWDESCR2",
        TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary,
    });

    var view = new ViewCreationInformation();
    view.Title = "NewVIEW";
    list.Views.Add(view);

    ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Here the view named "NewVIEW" will be created. How I can specify the specific view for current list which alredy exists ? (if I don't need to create any new view)

Are information about views stored in a SP database ? How I can retrieve this info ?

Comment: I suggest to rewrite your question as I am struggling myself to understand what it is you are looking for. You can create lists, you can create views, you can setup a specific view as the default view of a list, etc. Not sure what you mean by "restore". In order to get the view you just created, you can use View newView = views.Add(view);

Comment: @TiagoDuarte   done =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you specify that a view is the default view of a list:

```
ViewCreationInformation view = new ViewCreationInformation();
view.SetAsDefaultView = true;
```

If you want to do this after creating the view,

```
View newView = list.Views.Add(view);
newView.DefaultView = true;
```

Comment: Do you know where I can find a info about a view ? Imagine, that a disaster happened and I need to restore my SP site, but only I have is a backuped SP database. Can i get info about views from this db and how.

Comment: you can save a list as template, which would export it into a file that you can later import. you can also save the schema of the list into a xml file that you can use to re-create the list later.

Comment: yes, I can. But also I guess this new created view is stored in the sp database because of this view has a guid ID.

Comment: yes it is. you can grab the view by id, or by title, or something, and get the properties such as the title, url, order and viewfields...

Comment: and my extra question is how i can do this by t-sql (which table of Sp db constains this info) ?

Comment: that's something that will easily get you in trouble if you ask here. writing and even reading directly from the content database is not recommended, and will break your microsoft support. possible or not, you should stick to the api which should be enough to give you everything you need. besides, information usually spans different tables and it will be a nightmare to read

Comment: anyway I have to do this =)